# Class 'PayPal' Not Found - Laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to integrate Paypal in my web app using this package:

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/netshell/paypal

I have installed it following the instructions.

The controller is:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use PayPal;
use Redirect;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PayPalController extends Controller {

    private $_apiContext;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->_apiContext = PayPal::ApiContext(
            config('services.paypal.client_id'),
            config('services.paypal.secret'));

        $this->_apiContext->setConfig(array(
            'mode' => 'sandbox',
            'service.EndPoint' => 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com',
            'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
            'log.LogEnabled' => true,
            'log.FileName' => storage_path('logs/paypal.log'),
            'log.LogLevel' => 'FINE'
        ));
    }

    public function getCheckout() {
        $payer = PayPal::Payer();
        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

        $amount = PayPal:: Amount();
        $amount->setCurrency('EUR');
        $amount->setTotal(42); // This is the simple way,
        // you can alternatively describe everything in the order separately;
        // Reference the PayPal PHP REST SDK for details.

        $transaction = PayPal::Transaction();
        $transaction->setAmount($amount);
        $transaction->setDescription('What are you selling?');

        $redirectUrls = PayPal:: RedirectUrls();
        $redirectUrls->setReturnUrl(action('PayPalController@getDone'));
        $redirectUrls->setCancelUrl(action('PayPalController@getCancel'));

        $payment = PayPal::Payment();
        $payment->setIntent('sale');
        $payment->setPayer($payer);
        $payment->setRedirectUrls($redirectUrls);
        $payment->setTransactions(array($transaction));

        $response = $payment->create($this->_apiContext);
        $redirectUrl = $response->links[1]->href;

        return Redirect::to( $redirectUrl );
    }

    public function getDone(Request $request) {
        $id = $request->get('paymentId');
        $token = $request->get('token');
        $payer_id = $request->get('PayerID');

        $payment = PayPal::getById($id, $this->_apiContext);

        $paymentExecution = PayPal::PaymentExecution();

        $paymentExecution->setPayerId($payer_id);
        $executePayment = $payment->execute($paymentExecution, $this->_apiContext);

        // Clear the shopping cart, write to database, send notifications, etc.

        // Thank the user for the purchase
        return view('checkout.done');
    }

    public function getCancel() {
        // Curse and humiliate the user for cancelling this most sacred payment (yours)
        return view('checkout.cancel');
    }

}
```

I then created a route:

```
Route::get('/paypal/checkout', [
    'as' => 'get-paypal-checkout', 'uses' => 'PayPalController@getCheckout'
]);
```

But, when I go to that route I get:

> FatalErrorException in PayPalController.php line 14:
>   Class 'PayPal' not found
>   in PayPalController.php line 14

From what I can see, I've done my namespacing and `use` correctly.
New to all this.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks!

EDIT:

I've changed the top of PayPalController.php to:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Netshell\PayPal;
use Redirect;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
```

But it still doesn't work. `Class 'Netshell\PayPal' not found`

Comment: I think the Namespace is wrong, try `use Netshell/Paypal` in `PayPalController`

Comment: Tried it and still get error. Check my edit on OP.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It might be because of the typo you have in the class name. `use Paypal;` rather than `use PayPal;`.

Comment: Also tried that: `Class 'Netshell\Paypal' not found`

Comment: @kriiV Use only `use Paypal;` without `Netshell`.

Comment: That worked! Now I get: `Action App\Http\Controllers\PayPalController@getDone not defined.`

Comment: Hey did you solve your problem cause i got the same problem too. Action App\Http\Controllers\PayPalController@getDone not defined.

Comment: The example code in [git net-shell/laravel-paypal package](https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal#example-controller) should be updated. Thanks mate !

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem, but here is solution:
add in providers list:

```
Anouar\Paypalpayment\PaypalpaymentServiceProvider::class,
```

and in aliases:

```
'Paypal' => Anouar\Paypalpayment\Facades\PaypalPayment::class,
```

and will works.

Answer (score 0):

See the file `PayPal.php` here: https://github.com/net-shell/laravel-paypal/blob/master/src/Netshell/Paypal/Paypal.php (you could also find this in your project after adding it with composer here: `vendor/Netshell/Paypal` most likely)

The first line shows the namespace is: `namespace Netshell\Paypal;`

Update your `PayPalController.php` with `use Netshell/Paypal` instead of `use Paypal` and it should work.

Comment: Can you see the file in your vendor directory? What does your `composer.json` required array look like?

Answer (score 0):

check aliases and make sure its PayPal and not Paypal ('PayPal'    => Netshell\Paypal\Facades\Paypal::class,)